# Inflation adjusted prices package?

Tags: r

Say I've got a data.frame with prices in one column and years in another:

```
prices <- rnorm(200, mean=10, sd=3)
years <- round(rnorm(200, mean=2006, sd=5))
df <- data.frame(prices, years)
```

Now say I want to normalize all these prices to 2008 dollars using the consumer price index. I could go look the conversion values up and do the calculation manually, but my intuition tells me that there is probably a package to do this automagically. A search of r-seek and cran did not yield anything obvious.

Does anyone know of anything?

Comment: You can use `getSymbols` from `quantmod` to download CPI data from FRED.  I'm not sure which you want, but you can look [here](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/tags/series/?t=cpi).  e.g. `getSymbols("CPIAUCSL", src='FRED')` will download the **Consumer Price Index for All Urban Consumers: All Items**

Comment: @GSee why a comment and not an answer? This seems pretty complete.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get CPI data from [FRED](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/) using the 
`FRED` method of the `getSymbols` function in the 
[quantmod](http://cran.us.r-project.org/package=quantmod) package

```
getSymbols("CPIAUCSL", src='FRED') #Consumer Price Index for All Urban Consumers: All Items
#[1] "CPIAUCSL"
tail(CPIAUCSL)
#           CPIAUCSL
#2012-03-01  229.098
#2012-04-01  229.177
#2012-05-01  228.527
#2012-06-01  228.618
#2012-07-01  228.723
#2012-08-01  230.102

# make an `xts` object of prices
set.seed(1)
p <- xts(rnorm(63, mean=10, sd=3), seq(from=as.Date('1950-12-01'), by='years', length.out=63))
colnames(p) <- "price"
```

The [CPI inflation calculator at the BLS](http://www.bls.gov/data/inflation_calculator.htm)

> ... uses the average Consumer Price Index for a given calendar year... 
>   For the current year, the latest monthly index value is used.

(For this answer, I'm going to ignore the second part of the [above quote](http://data.bls.gov/cpi/cpicalc.htm)...)

So, calculate an annual average

```
avg.cpi <- apply.yearly(CPIAUCSL, mean)
```

Then divide all index levels by the base price to create a conversion factor

```
cf <- avg.cpi/as.numeric(avg.cpi['2008']) #using 2008 as the base year
dat <- merge(p, cf, all=FALSE)
dat$adj <- dat[, 1] * dat[, 2]

tail(dat)
#               price  CPIAUCSL       adj
#2006-12-01  8.898336 0.9363693  8.332128
#2007-12-01  6.867596 0.9632483  6.615200
#2008-12-01 11.709159 1.0000000 11.709159
#2009-12-01  9.594836 0.9967933  9.564069
#2010-12-01 17.204853 1.0131453 17.431015
#2011-12-01  9.882280 1.0449769 10.326754
```

Comment: Nicely done. Going out and manually fetching the CPI was exactly what I was trying to do more intelligently.

Comment: @Peter, you're going to love [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com).  You also might like [qmao](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1113)

Comment: I might be completely crazy but don't you want to divide by the conversion factor? 2006 dollars are worth more in 2008 rather than less and 2011 dollars should be worth more right?

Comment: @AdamMccurdy If dollars are worth more, that means prices are lower; you can buy more goods with the same amount of dollars, so the price must be lower.

Comment: @GSee of course, I was pretty sure that I had missed something obvious. I was stuck thinking about the value of dollars not of prices. Thanks for addressing a silly question.

Answer (score 11):

There is a much simpler solution for acquiring the annual CPI (e.g., CPIAUCSL) that does not require use of the `quantmod` package, which seems to always have compatibility issues for one reason or another, at least in my experience.

```
require(lubridate) || install.packages("lubridate")
require(dplyr) || install.packages("dplyr")
monthly_cpi <-
  read.table("http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/CPIAUCSL.txt",
             skip = 53, header = TRUE)
monthly_cpi$cpi_year <- year(monthly_cpi$DATE)
yearly_cpi <- monthly_cpi %.% group_by(cpi_year) %.% summarize(cpi = mean(VALUE))
```

Then, to create your adjustment factor relative to say, last year's prices:

```
yearly_cpi$adj_factor <- yearly_cpi$cpi/yearly_cpi$cpi[yearly_cpi$cpi_year == 2013]
```

You have to find out how many lines to `skip`, but then again, that causes you to actually look at the lines that are skipped by viewing the actual data source, which happens to have useful preamble information.

**BUT WAIT! THERE'S MORE!**

Thanks to @GSee (who gave the checked answer) for noting that there is a `.csv` version for which you need not skip any rows! Using this version, the code is:

```
require(lubridate) || install.packages("lubridate")
require(dplyr) || install.packages("dplyr")
monthly_cpi <-
  read.csv("http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/CPIAUCSL.csv", header = TRUE)
monthly_cpi$cpi_year <- year(monthly_cpi$DATE)
yearly_cpi <- monthly_cpi %.% group_by(cpi_year) %.% summarize(cpi = mean(VALUE))
yearly_cpi$adj_factor <- yearly_cpi$cpi/yearly_cpi$cpi[yearly_cpi$cpi_year == 2013]
```

Comment: Did you know there's a CSV version? http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/CPIAUCSL.csv

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be noted that GSee's solution is technically correct but probably isn't want most people want when they talk about adjusting for inflation.

In my experience most people want to know how much an item purchased in years past would cost in today's dollars.

Based on GSee's code, this yields:

```
as.numeric(avg.cpi['2008'])/avg.cpi
dat <- merge(p, cf, all=FALSE)
dat$adj <- dat[, 1] * dat[, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `priceR`, like so:

```
library(priceR)
set.seed(123)
prices <- rnorm(10, mean=10, sd=3)
years <- round(rnorm(10, mean=2006, sd=5))
df <- data.frame(years, nominal_prices)

df$in_2008_dollars <- adjust_for_inflation(prices, years, "US", to_date = 2008)


df
##    years nominal_prices in_2008_dollars
## 1   2012        8.31857         7.66782
## 2   2008        9.30947         9.30947
## 3   2008       14.67612        14.67612
## 4   2007       10.21153        10.60356
## 5   2003       10.38786        12.15782
## 6   2015       15.14519        13.26473
## 7   2008       11.38275        11.38275
## 8   1996        6.20482         8.51713
## 9   2010        7.93944         7.67319
## 10  2004        8.66301         9.87471
```

**Notes**

- Example from [here](https://github.com/stevecondylios/priceR#inflation)
- This uses CPI data from World Bank
- `adjust_for_inflation()` works for all countries. Use `show_countries()` for more info.

Comment: Nice! this is simple and works without adding a bunch of tidyverse dependencies or translating to ts objects.